# Change layout weight programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set the layout weight of a `view` programmatically **to a random number**. I think I have the right approach, but I am unable to get some of the technical details. This is what I have so far:

```
public class EnterText extends Activity {

    View view = findViewById(R.id.view1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_text);

        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(5 - 1) + 1;

        //This is to put the weight in a format like "1f"
        String weight = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i1)).append("f").toString();

        int height1;
        view.getLayoutParams().height = height1;    

        int width1;
        view.getLayoutParams().height = width1; 

        //Set the weight
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.height1, LayoutParams.width1, weight));

    }

}
```

I believe this is close to working, but I am running into some errors. First, I get the error `The method StringBuilder(String) is undefined for the type EnterText`, which I don't think should be occurring. Second, at `0dip`, I get the errors `Syntax error on token ".0d", . expected`. Does anyone know how to fix this, and does anyone know a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

after the setContentView call add the reference to the view there

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_text);
    view = findViewById(R.id.view1);
```

for `StringBuilder(String) is undefined for the type EnterText`, use the `new` keyword to make a new StringBuilder (i dont think you need this tho)

```
String weight = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i1)).append("f").toString();
```

for `Syntax error on token ".0d", . expected`, just use getLayoutParams().weight and assign it a float not an int value,

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lllp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
lllp.weight = 0.25f
view.setLayoutParams(lllp); // this one may not be needed
```

should look something like :

```
View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_text);
    view = findViewById(R.id.view1);


    //Set the weight using a float n

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lllp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    lllp.weight = 0.25f; // supply a float like this
    int height1 = 200; // you have to supply a value
    int width1 = 300;  // you have to supply a value
    lllp.width = width1;
    lllp.height = height1; 
    view.setLayoutParams(lllp); // this one may not be needed

}
```

Comment: Please see my updated code, when I tried your second suggestion I got a different error. But your first one works!

Comment: When I try this, I get the error `height1 cannot be resolved or is not a field`, and `width1 cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: Are you sure your updated answer works? Now it says that `The value of the local variable weight is not used`

Comment: sorry..was making edits based on your edits..  see my new edit

Comment: Cool, but does your code have the random element that was in mine? Or do I insert that in the middle?

Comment: I'm not sure what the random number is for (so I removed it) ? can you explain? you can add it back in and assign values to `lllp` however you like as long as its the right type and initialised like the code above.

Comment: Yeah sure, the random number is so that `lllp.weight` gets a random value, such as `1f, 2f ... 5f`. Could I just set lllp.weight equal to `new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i1)).append("f").toString()`, where `i1` is the random value?

Comment: you cant assign a weight using a string (what StringBuilder helps you  create), you need to supply a float like `0.35f`